# aws cli not finding region in source profile for one profile, but works with another

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a `~/.aws/config` that looks something like this:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1

[profile foo]
region = us-east-1

[profile foo-iam-manager]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::012345678984:role/iam-manager
    source_profile = foo

[profile foo-secrets-manager]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::012345678984:role/secrets-manager
    source_profile = foo
```

If I run:

```
aws --profile foo-iam-manager iam list-roles
```

It works great!

But if I run:

```
aws --profile foo-secrets-manager secretsmanager list-secrets
```

Then it fails with:

```
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```

And indeed, if I update `~/.aws/config` to look like...

```
[default]
region = us-east-1

[profile foo]
region = us-east-1

[profile foo-iam-manager]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::012345678984:role/iam-manager
    source_profile = foo

[profile foo-secrets-manager]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::012345678984:role/secrets-manager
    source_profile = foo
    region = us-east-1
```

...then everything works. Why does the `foo-iam-manager` profile work
just fine without a region setting in the profile, but
`foo-secrets-manager` requires one? I thought it would pull the
appropriate value from the `source_profile` setting.

Comment: That test isn't a good comparison because IAM is a regionless services while secretsmanager is region specific.

Comment: See, now I've learned something. But it still seems as if should use the region setting from `source_profile`. I've been poking around the AWS docs and I can't find anything definitive on which behavior I should expect.

Comment: Source profile specifies another profile whose credentials are used to assume the role specified the current profile. That's it, it does not provides fallback for the region if there is no region for the current profile. That being said, I've seen enough inconsistencies in the CLI and the AWS console to assume that there might be some service which would fall back on the region specified by the source profile.